# Is it possible to access files stored in TFS’s source control from the TFSBuild.proj file before the “Get” build task?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks

I’m using a few custom MSBuild tasks that are checked into source control. I would like to import these tasks into my TFSBuild.proj file that TFS uses to build the project. Right now I have created a 2nd project file that includes all of the uses of these custom tasks. I do this because I can run this project file after the workspace has been created and the files have been downloaded.

Is there a way to reference the files on the server from the build project so that I don’t have to do this 2 step process?

I wish the following would work.

```
<Import Project="$/My/Server/Path/Custom.tasks.targets" />
```

This question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97349/tfsbuild-proj-and-importing-external-targets). In my case the tasks are checked into source control so that the build machines don't have another required install. Placing the tasks locally doesn't work very well in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the tasks and the .targets file(s) in the same version control folder as your TFSBuild.proj file (or in a sub-directory beneath it), TFS Build will download all of that content to your build agent prior to kicking off your build script.